# How to render a simple bundled web app in Electron?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, electron

Trying to render a simple Typescript/HTML app bundle in Electron.

The app to render renders and works perfectly when I drag its index.html onto a Chrome tab.

Here's what I have done:

- Generated an electron app with electron-forge and template webpack-typescript
- Bundled a separate app up with webpack, resulting in what we would expect: myapp/dist/bundle.js and myapp/dist/index.html
- Copied myapp/dist folder over into the electron project, and **updated one** of the scaffolded electron files as follows:

```js
// forge.config.ts--updated entryPoints/html to point to HTML of app to be rendered:

. . .
renderer: {
  config: rendererConfig,
  entryPoints: [
    {
      html: './dist-app/index.html', // <== THIS IS NEW
      js: './src/renderer.ts',
      name: 'main_window',
      preload: {
        js: './src/preload.ts',
      },
    },
  ],
. . .
```

the HTML for the app is simply:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script defer src="bundle.js"></script>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is an empty Electron window, and the following two Electron console error messages:

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
- Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Can someone help to overcome this block? This has to be simple. Have I not pointed Electron to the app-to-render correctly?
Thx!